# How to execute react callback when a toolbar button is pressed as a part of CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react

There is a React project and CKEditor 5 custom classic build.

Let's say we have a React component `App` which renders `<CKEditor5 />` as a part of JSX. As for CKEditor itself, its toolbar has a custom button.

```
export const App = () => {
  // It should be executed on click
  const callbackToRun = useCallback(() => {
    // any logic to execute on toolbar's button click
  }, []);

  return (
    // CKE has a custom button in a toolbar. We'd like to run a callback when it is pressed.
    <CKEditor5 />
  );
}
```

What is an optimal approach to run a React logic (aka function/callback) that resides in the parent React component 'App' when we click on a button on CKE5 toolbar?

***From what I think, there are such options as:***

1. **Pass a callback as a part of config**, extract it from a config when we click on a toolbar button inside a custom command.

```
export const App = () => {
  const callbackToRun = useCallback(() => {}, []);

  return (
    <CKEditor5 config={callbackToRun} />
  );
}
```

Next, we implement a basic command that extracts callback from a config and run it. The command is bound to a button click as a part of UI CKEditor5 logic (skipping this part of code, it is pretty common).

```
import { Command } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core';

export class HandleToolbarButtonClickCommand extends Command {
    execute() {
        this.editor.config.get('callbackToRun')();
    }
}
```

2. Second possible approach is to **get an instance of editor** to React parent component. Then **listen to execute event** or similar event.

```
export const App = () => {
  const editorInstance = useRef(null);
  const handleReady = (editor) => editorInstance.current = editor;

  const callbackToRun = useCallback(() => {}, []);

  // ??? Should we listen to execute command somehow or toolbar button click somehow?
  useEffect(() => {
    // Pseudo code below
    // editorInstance.listenTo(..., callbackToRun);
  }, []);

  return (
    <CKEditor5 onReady={handleReady} />
  );
}
```

**What is the best way to handle a such situation when the part of react logic must be executed on a CKEditor5 toolbar button click?**